# Why when I call gotoDate of fullCalender, it only increments day by day?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I want fullCalendar to go to one a specifical day, but when I call

```
$('#calendarContainer').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
```

It only increment the view of the actual date by one.

My variable date is

```
var date =$.fullCalendar.moment(moment.utc(app.mCurrentStartDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

My only way to make it work was to do

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    $('#calendarContainer').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
  }
```

But that is not possible.

My calendar use custom views

```
views: {
  agendaThreeDay: {
        type: 'agenda',
        duration: { days: 3 },
        buttonText: '3 day',
        columnFormat: 'dddd D MMMM',
    },
  agendaTwoDay: {
        type: 'agenda',
        duration: { days: 2 },
        buttonText: '2 day',
        columnFormat: 'dddd D MMMM',
    }
},
```

Do you know if this is the intented behaviour of gotoDate, or may be I use it the wrong way ? 
Thanks.

Comment: what fullcalendar version are you using?

Comment: @Daffy I am using the version 2.7.1

Comment: what does $.fullCalendar.moment(moment.utc(app.mCurrentStartDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')); actually equal

Comment: @Daffy it returns a moment.

Comment: I just tried it on Jsfiddle, it works.. for example try.....       $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', new Date("2017-01-22") );

Comment: Try using this as the date:

var date =$.fullCalendar.moment(moment.utc(app.mCurrentStartDate)).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

Comment: @NitinDhomse still doesn't work .. You can try to do it if you want in my own calendar https://dimitri-dev.facilitatrip.fr/apps/#! (top right button to display the calendar).

Comment: @DimitriDanilov Why I need to signup to visit your calendar?

Comment: he just said...button near the top-right that looks like a calendar. And use the choose dates option and press ok to make it change the calendar date. am I right?

Comment: Thanks @ADyson, I got it.

Comment: @DimitriDanilov I just tried it on that link you gave, changing the start date  to 10th August and it seems to work fine. Can you give an example of a date that doesn't work?

Comment: @ADyson When you enter your dates in the popup, thats works fine for me too. But when in the console I try to do it manualiy with $('#calendarContainer').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date); that doesn't work anymore

Comment: Ok. I assume the value of date when you do it from the console is `$.fullCalendar.moment(moment.utc(app.mCurrentStartDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));` as described in the question? In which case, what is the value of `app.mCurrentStartDate`?

Comment: @ADyson It contains a date in string format "2017-01-24"

Comment: In fact I tried every date combinaison in the console, and everything has the same behaviour, the view only increments by one.

Comment: if it's already in YYYY-MM-DD format I don't think you need to do the whole `$.fullCalendar.moment`... business at all. You can just pass the string directly to the gotoDate method: `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', app.mCurrentStartDate);` should work. It's a moment-able string already. I just tested in a little page of my own and that should work.

Comment: I tried to give it a string, and it changes nothing. I tried also to call goToDate from a jsfiddle and thart works fine. But I don't understand why I can't make it work on my page.

Comment: just tried it in your page. As shown by the console logs which appear, the viewRender event in calendar.js (which fires after goToDate is called as per the fullCalendar docs) is interfering with it. Check out the two "if" statements which call gotoDate and add/subtract the date by one day. So obviously that will appear to cancel the date you had input. For some reason that doesn't seem to always happen when doing it via the UI, but sometimes it does. It's for you to determine what the purpose of the code in viewRender is, whether that's correct or not!

Comment: @ADyson Yes you are right, I do some date controle operations in viewRender ! That must be that ! Thank you.